# What is the axiom of induction for natural numbers?

Tags: induction

Could you please explain me what is the axiom of induction for natural numbers?

I'm confused what this question is asking, I think I'm just suppose to explain how induction is used in regards to natural numbers?

Comment: Where did you see the question?  What course?  Yes, I would think you were being asked for a short essay on what it is and why it is used.

Comment: that would be correct

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to state it exactly, but basically the axiom of induction states that "if a statement is true for 1, and if the statement is true for $N+1$ whenever it is true for $N$, then it is true for every natural number." Does that help?

Comment: Some times the natural numbers start at $0$, not $1$, though, and in those cases you need to change this statement ever so slightly.

Comment: ok i got it, it means that n+1 proceeds the number n in regards to natural numbers?